# Android Which Fragment (and Activity) to Use

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library

I have a library of Android code that I use throughout my Android projects. I created it a while back, and it uses the v4 support library (any `Fragment` subclasses inherit its `Fragment`, and all my `Activity`s are `FragmentActivity`s).

In most of my projects I have a `BaseActivity` class that inherits from `FragmentActivity` so that I don't have to worry about accidentally defining a non-support library `Activity` and try to use one of the `Fragment`s from the support library. I put a lot of my application specific boilerplate in this `BaseActivity`.

I'm now working out the logistics of dropping support for one of my apps for devices below ICS. I have found a few issues regarding how to continue to use my Android library, which mostly boil down to whether I should continue to use FragmentActivity and the support library's Fragment even after dropping support for HC-.

I'm stuck between the convenience of "native `Fragment` and `ActionBar` and the new capabilities they come with, and the backwards compatible nature of the support library (eg, nested fragments for 4.0-4.1).

Anyone have any input as to whether I should keep using the support library, or if it's worth it to find some way to have a ridiculous amount of version checking and code overhead to provide implementations for versions that needs the support library and versions that can use the current API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest keeping the support library implementations. This allows you use things like ViewPagers without worrying or mixing and matching implementations. It also ensures that the underlying code won't change on you until you update the support library jar.